Why my NestJs MySQL React application fails to get database content on the phone at same local network?
I have the NestJS server running locally on my PC at IP http://192.168.100.5 (the React client the same).
I'm connecting to MySQL database inside NestJS.
I've set rule to allow inbound connections on port 3000 in Windows. So if I go in the phone browser and call  http://192.168.100.5:3000/clients I get the database content. If I try the React port http://192.168.100.5:3001 I get the application but without the database content.
React .env
REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL=http://192.168.100.5:3000

NestJS main.ts
  app.enableCors({
    origin: '*', 
    methods: 'GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS',
    credentials: true,
  });

  await app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');
}


If you open the browser console, do you get any errors? (On Android with Google Chrome  follow https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging to get the developer tools working)

Thanks, solved it! One API_URL was set to localhost instead of the .env REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL.
